# Label not showing properly in scrollview section

Tags: kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

The last few lines of my label are not showing. I want my label to show properly on my screen using ScrollView widget I tried this but ScrollView is not working unless it has more few lines but as I increase the lines And as I scroll again last lines not come up properly. In short, I want as my length of text increases the scroll view shows properly every line of my label and the space between paragraphs also not showing

here's my code of .kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'

        NavigationLayout:

            ScreenManager:

                Screen:

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Story"
                        anchor_title: 'left'
                        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

             MDNavigationDrawer:
                    title: 'Story A Day'
                    id: nav_drawer
                    swipe_distance: 10

                    ContentNavigationDrawer:
                        id: content_drawer
                        screen_manager: screen_manager
                        nav_drawer: nav_drawer


<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                pos: root.pos
                size: root.size
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                text:
                    """
                    A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy
                    had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                    sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he
                    would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                    sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                    The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest
                    marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                    The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised.
                    That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                    could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl
                    has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                    hidden the best marbles from her.

                    Moral of the Story :

                    If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                    you will always kept doubting if the other person
                    has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                    for any relationship like love, employee –
                    employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                    and the most of the feelings we get now
                    days are just merely just the impact of the
                    surrounding now days we dont have a good
                    feeling that last long
                    and now we have to just name it in that way
                    """
                font_size: '20sp'
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                size: self.texture_size
                text_size: root.width, None
                size_hint_x: 1.0
                size_hint_y: None
                halign: "auto"
                valign: "middle"
```

Comment: In your 'kv', you have two rules for `MainScreen`. The first rule, under the `ScreenManager:` rule, creates a `MainScreen` that contains a `NavigationLayout` that fills the entire `MainScreen`. Then, the `<MainScreen>` rule adds a `BoxLayout` to the `MainScreen`, and that also fills the entire `MainScreen`. Where in your `MainScreen` do you want that `BoxLayout` located? It generally makes layout easier if you place you entire `MainScreen` layout in one rule.

Comment: So in which rule I should place it

Comment: That is up to you, but I have typically seen the `<MainScreen>:` rule containing all the details of the `MainScreen`, with the `ScreenManager:` rule just containing a reference , like `MainScreen:`.

Comment: I would do the `ScreenManager:` rule with just `MainScreen:` in it. Then all the `MainScreen` details in a ` <MainScreen>:` rule.

Comment: But the spaces between the paragraph is also not showing what should  I do with it, can you please answer this and write the code for it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `kv` file with the `ScreenManager:` rule just listing the child `Screens`:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManager:
    id: screens

    FirstScreen:

    AboutUs:

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    background_color: 2, 3, 4, 5
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

        MDLabel:
            anchor_y: 'left'
            text: "[b]Story A Day[/b]"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            markup: True
            font_style: "H4"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Story A Day'
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            MDExpansionPanelTwoLine:
                text: 'send us your idea'
                secondary_text: 'email: xxxxx@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            TwoLineAvatarListItem:
                text: 'Send us your story'
                secondary_text: 'to: Story_A_Day@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text: "About Us"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    app.root.transition.direction = 'right'
                    app.root.current = "screen1"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "information"
                    on_release:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        app.root.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.5)
                        app.root.current = "screen1"

<AboutUs>:
    name: 'screen1'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'close'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.97}
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_release:
            app.root.transition.direction = 'right'
            app.root.current = "main"
    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        text: """[b]About Us [/b]"""
        markup: True
        font_size: '40sp'
        text_size: None, None
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        pos_hint: {'top':1}

    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        font_size: '18sp'
        text_size: self.width, 100
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"
        text: 
            """"""

<Share>
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        data: root.data
        icon: 'share-variant'
        opening_time: 0.5
        callback: root.callback   # on pressing the call stack buttons
        color_icon_root_button: 0, 0, 0, 1  # color of icon of button
        color_icon_stack_button: 0, 0, 0, 1
        hint_animation: True
        rotation_root_button: False


<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                MDToolbar:
                    id: toolbar
                    title: "Story"
                    anchor_title: 'left'
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: root.height - toolbar.height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    ScrollView:
                        Label:
                            text:
                                """
                                A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy
                                had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                                sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he
                                would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                                sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                                The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest
                                marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                                The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised.
                                That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                                could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl
                                has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                                hidden the best marbles from her.

                                Moral of the Story :

                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                """
                            font_size: '20sp'
                            text_color: 255,255,255, 0
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text_size: root.width, None
                            size_hint_x: 1.0
                            size_hint_y: None
                            halign: "auto"
                            valign: "middle"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            title: 'Story A Day'
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_distance: 10

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                screen_manager: app.root
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

I noticed that you were doing the same thing with `AboutUs`, so I also modified that so that all of its layout is now in the `<AboutUs>:` rule. Since your `ScreenManager` is now in a different rule from your `Screens`, you cannot access it using its `id` (`ids` are only valid within the same rule). So `Screen` changes can be done using `app.root.current`.

I think that the `screen_manager: app.root` is not working because the `app` is not yet available when that expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManager:
    id: screens

    FirstScreen:

    AboutUs:
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'close'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.97}
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release:
                screens.transition.direction = 'right'
                screens.current = "main"

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    background_color: 2, 3, 4, 5
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

        MDLabel:
            anchor_y: 'left'
            text: "[b]Story A Day[/b]"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            markup: True
            font_style: "H4"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Story A Day'
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            MDExpansionPanelTwoLine:
                text: 'send us your idea'
                secondary_text: 'email: xxxxx@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            TwoLineAvatarListItem:
                text: 'Send us your story'
                secondary_text: 'to: Story_A_Day@gmail.com'

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "email"

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text: "About Us"
                on_release:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screens.transition.direction = 'right'
                    root.screens.current = "main"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "information"
                    on_release:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        screens.transition = FadeTransition(duration=0.5)
                        screens.current = "screen1"

<AboutUs>:
    name: 'screen1'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        text: """[b]About Us [/b]"""
        markup: True
        font_size: '40sp'
        text_size: None, None
        size_hint: 1, 1.9
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    Label:
        text_color: 255, 255, 255, 0
        font_size: '18sp'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: 1, 1.5
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"
        text:
            """"""

<Share>
    MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
        data: root.data
        icon: 'share-variant'
        opening_time: 0.5
        callback: root.callback   # on pressing the call stack buttons
        color_icon_root_button: 0, 0, 0, 1  # color of icon of button
        color_icon_stack_button: 0, 0, 0, 1
        hint_animation: True
        rotation_root_button: False


<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                MDToolbar:
                    id: toolbar
                    title: "Story"
                    anchor_title: 'left'
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: root.height - toolbar.height
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    ScrollView:
                        Label:
                            text:
                                """
                                A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy
                                had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                                sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he
                                would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                                sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                                The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest
                                marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                                The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised.
                                That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                                could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl
                                has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                                hidden the best marbles from her.

                                Moral of the Story :

                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                """
                            font_size: '20sp'
                            text_color: 255,255,255, 0
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text_size: root.width, None
                            size_hint_x: 1.0
                            size_hint_y: None
                            halign: "auto"
                            valign: "middle"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            title: 'Story A Day'
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_distance: 10

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                screens: app.root
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing at where you actually want the `BoxLayout`, but here is how I would do it:

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'

    NavigationLayout:
        id: nav_layout

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                MDToolbar:
                    id: toolbar
                    title: "Story"
                    anchor_title: 'left'
                    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                    elevation: 10
                    left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: root.height - toolbar.height
                    ScrollView:
                        Label:
                            text:
                                """
                                A boy and a girl were playing together. The boy
                                had a collection of marbles. The girl has some
                                sweets with her. The boy told the girl that he
                                would give her all his marbles in exchange for the
                                sweets with her. The girl agreed.

                                The boy kept the most beautiful and the biggest
                                marbles with him and gave her the remaining marbles.
                                The girl gave him all her sweets as she promised.
                                That night the girl slept peacefully. But the boy
                                could not sleep as he kept wondering if the girl
                                has hidden some sweets from him the way he had
                                hidden the best marbles from her.

                                Moral of the Story :

                                If you do not give 100 percent in a relationship,
                                you will always kept doubting if the other person
                                has given her / his hundred percent. This is applicable
                                for any relationship like love, employee –
                                employer, friendship, family, countries, etc
                                and the most of the feelings we get now
                                days are just merely just the impact of the
                                surrounding now days we dont have a good
                                feeling that last long
                                and now we have to just name it in that way
                                """
                            font_size: '20sp'
                            color: 0,0,0,1
                            height: self.texture_size[1]
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text_size: root.width, None
                            size_hint_x: 1.0
                            size_hint_y: None
                            halign: "auto"
                            valign: "middle"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            title: 'Story A Day'
            id: nav_drawer
            swipe_distance: 10

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
                screen_manager: app.root
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked really but now I'm not able to change my screen here's the complete kv file in my answer can you please help me with that I'll be really grateful to you

Comment: screen_manager: app.root how does it work bcoz in my case it's not working